# How to update effective dates for historic data while loading daily data

Tags: snowflake-schema, scd2

I am having issue with updating effective end_date for products in scd type 2 where daily current_flag row have the same pack_size and product_code. Current statement does not handle it and it skips the row as there is no match. My example product dimension looks like below for example product_code.

Product dimension:

[image: product dimension]

The daily data I am trying to load looks like below:

[image: daily data to load]

I would expect to see the end result looking like below:

[image: expected results]

But what I am getting instead is:

[image: current results]

My statement looks like below:

```
MERGE INTO
    dim_table_product AS target_table
    USING
        (
            SELECT product_code,
                   pack_size,
                   case_size,
                   end_date
            FROM input_table_products
        ) AS source_table
    ON
        (
                CAST(target_table.product_code AS INT) = CAST(source_table.product_code AS INT)
            )
    WHEN MATCHED
        AND target_table.cur_flag = 1
            AND (
                        COALESCE(target_table.pack_size, 'C0AL3SC3')
                        <> COALESCE(source_table.pack_size, 'C0AL3SC3')
                    OR COALESCE(target_table.case_size, 'C0AL3SC3')
                            <> COALESCE(source_table.case_size, 'C0AL3SC3')
                )
        THEN
        UPDATE SET
            target_table.updated = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(),
            target_table.end_date = source_table.end_date,
            cur_flag = 0
```

Could you please advise how I could resolve this issue and get the expected results ?

Thank you !

Comment: Is this supposed to be under the snowflake-schema tag instead of snowflake-data-warehouse?

Comment: Is it possible that a key (11) is in a single source file more than once?  If you are expecting them to happen in order, I'm not sure a merge statement will work.

Comment: Nope. There is only one occurrence of product_code in the source file.

Comment: The only way to work it out is to load the days one by one but ideally I would like to go with a bulk load.